# Is it possible in oracle to trigger a SAS program after an insert or update on oracle table?

Tags: oracle, sas

I'm new to oracle and I saw Oracle triggers can trigger some action after an update or insert is done on oracle table.
Is it possible to trigger a SAS program after every update or insert on Oracle table.

Comment: Are you trying to do this from the Oracle side, or SAS side?

Comment: Haven't tried...but planning to do it from Oracle side if it works that way.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few different ways to do this but a problem like this is an example of the saying "Just because you can, doesn't mean you should".

So sure, your trigger can be fired on update or insert and that can call a stored procedure in a package which can use the [oracle host command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12026.htm) to call an operating system command which can call SAS.

Here are some questions:

- do you really want to install SAS on the same machine as your Oracle database?
- do you really want every transaction that inserts or updates to have to wait until the host command completes?  What if SAS is down?  Do you want the transaction to complete or.....?
- do you really want the account that runs the database to have privileges to start up or send information to other executables?  Think security risks.
- if an insert does one record the action is clear.  What if an update affects a thousand records?  What message do you want to send to SAS?  One thousand update statements?  One update statement?

There are better ways to do this but a complete answer needs more details from you as to the end goal and business logic involved.  Some ways I have used include:

- trigger inserts data into an [Oracle advanced queue](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e11013/aq_intro.htm#ADQUE0100). At predetermined intervals take the changes off the queue and write them to a flat file.  Write a file watcher to look for the files and send the info to SAS.
- write a Java program to take the changes and ship them
- use the APEX web service and expose the changes as a series of JSON or REST packets.

Comment: :1)SAS is already installed on Linux and I would like to trigger a SAS process on LINUX.    2)Yes, I want every transaction that inserts or updates to have to wait until the host command completes and then trigger SAS. If SAS is down then send a notification.     3)Its okay if the account that runs the database to have privileges to start up or send information to other executables like SAS on LINUX.     4) When ever a change occurred on oracle table, once the change is done I want to trigger SAS program which connects to oracle and uses that oracle table in further calculations.